# Multiple Post requests in WebApi with same parameter types and different [Route("/cars")]/[RoutePrefix("api/v1/data")]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consolidate WebAPI controllers with duplicate operations to limit controller sprawl.  This would require multiple posts for one controller "with the same parameter types" see error below when I try to do this using [RoutePrefix("")] and different method level [Route("")]

**What could I do to allow the multiple Post requests?**

**Error:** CS0111 Type 'DataController' already defines a member called 'Post' with the same parameter types

WebApi version from **packages.config**

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net461" />
```

**Example code:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace UberCool.v1.Data.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/v1/data")]
    public class DataController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("/cars")]
        public List<Cars> Post()
        {
            var response = new CarsSFTP().GetData();
            return response;
        }

        [Route("/trucks")]
        public List<Trucks> Post()
        {
            var response = new TrucksSFTP().GetData();
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Call them PostCars and PostTrucks. But actually, why Post when you are *getting* cars and trucks?

Comment: I tried the prefix you suggested to the method name and that does work.  I didn't realize it string splits the first part of the method name for duplicates.   That solves my problem I was trying to solve.   As for the verb choice, I agree with you keep it standard this was just an example but I should use GET to make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

As ckuri suggested.

Leverage the HTTP Verb in the method name as a prefix.  Both of the below will be treated as Post requests.  If i include the routing they can be to the same controller but different methods.  Se the tweaked example code from above.

**- PostMyRandomMethod()

 - PostMyRandomMethod2()**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace UberCool.v1.Data.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/v1/data")]
    public class DataController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("/cars")]
        public List<Cars> PostMyRandomMethod()
        {
            var response = new CarsSFTP().GetData();
            return response;
        }

        [Route("/trucks")]
        public List<Trucks> PostMyRandomMethod2()
        {
            var response = new TrucksSFTP().GetData();
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this seems to be just for the IDE to detect errors it would be ideal to inspect the Route/RoutePrefix collections instead of throwing an error.